# pattern for return values

Tags: design-patterns, functional-programming

In validate methods what kind of return types or return value patterns are preferred?

If a validate function returns success/failure and failed fields as a result,
should the function return,
            array with {true/false, array of error fields]}
                          or
            true on success and array of error fields in case of failure

Comment: A discriminated union with the parsed value or a failure type. You didn't define the language so I arbitrarily chose F# :). Actually, the [Railway Oriented Programming](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/) pattern explains both what to return *and* how to use it to simplify a chain of functional calls

Comment: This actually comes down to what the *requirement specifies* . For example in a login validation window, you don't say which field is wrong.. whereas in account creation requirement, you say which field is wrong.. so, depending on the context, this answer changes.

Comment: @TheLostMind a *pattern* is a generic answer to this problem, that can cover multiple requirements. Union types are typically used for such scenarios in functional languages